# iPhone table menu

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi all i would like to build a menu that looks like a table and when i click on a cell it goes to another view. But i want for the tableView to be inside a UIView. I need starting points, like how it's done, not the actual coding. I dont want someone to write it for me

here are some examples on what i want

[image: 1.]

[image: and 2.]

Comment: You need to customize your table view cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Suggestion**

You could use a container view, it will have your UITableView as a subview.

```
UIView* m_OthersView;
UIView* m_ContainerView;
UIView* m_TableView;

[self.view addSubviews:m_ContainerView];
[self.view addSubviews:m_OthersView];
```

if you need menu in your view,

```
 [m_ContainerView addSubviews:m_TableView]
```

and if you don't

```
[m_TableView removeFromSuperview];
```

Thanks,

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can be a little more specific on this, i like this idea but i need more help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to accomplish is that background behind the table view and a custom size of the table view I suppose you could do the following in your `viewDidLoad` of the table view controller

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:background];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:background]; // Now the background should be behind the table view.
self.tableView.frame = yourFrame;
```

I haven't tried it, but I think it should work. If not let me know.